# Cómo seleccionar el área y lo que esta dentro de las fechas seleccionadas?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

¿Cómo seleccionar el área y lo que esta dentro de las fechas seleccionadas?

Estoy trabajando en una pagina web e hice un query para mostrar el área y los valores que le corresponden al área seleccionada dentro de las fechas seleccionadas.

Este es el query:

```
var consulta = "SELECT * FROM produccion WHERE fecha BETWEEN #" + fecha+"# AND #" + fechaFinal + "#";
```

Y esta es la tabla:

```
+----+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| id |   area   | grafica | grafica2 | grafica3 | grafica4 |   fecha   |
+----+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 40 |    IFE   |   90.5  |          |          |          |  4/2/2018 |
| 41 |    IFE   |         |   90.5   |          |          |  4/9/2018 |
| 42 |    IFE   |         |          |   90.5   |          | 4/16/2018 |
| 43 |    IFE   |         |          |          |   90.5   | 4/23/2018 |
| 44 | Seamless |   50.1  |          |          |          |  4/2/2018 |
| 45 | Seamless |         |   50.1   |          |          |  4/2/2018 |
| 46 | Seamless |         |          |   21.3   |          |  4/9/2018 |
+----+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Por favor, cambia esa imagen o adjunta mejor la estructura de la tabla, algo donde se pueda apreciar la estructura para poder ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Y... el problema cuál es? ¿En qué entra Javascript en esto? ¿Los caracteres `#` que representan en tu consulta?